# Найти слова с цифрой sql like

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть таблица `table1`

```
| ID  | Attr       |
+-----+------------+ 
| 169 | Jur9       |
| 169 | Jur9_name  |
| 169 | Jur10      |
| 169 | Jur10_name |
```

И запрос:

```
select *
  from table1
 where ID = 169
   and ATTR like 'Jur_';
```

Результат:

```
| ID  | Attr       |
+-----+------------+ 
| 169 | Jur9       |
```

Ожидаю результата:

```
    | ID  | Attr       |
    +-----+------------+ 
    | 169 | Jur9       |
    | 169 | Jur10      |
```

Как можно вытащить исключив Jur9_name и Jur10_name

Comment: Просил с цифрой? вот и получи - с цифрой. А не с числом. Используй REGEXP_LIKE. Или отбирай те, что НЕ содержат знак подчёркивания - тоже сойдёт для показанных значений.

Answer (score 2):

Tак как ответ ТС не отвечает на поставленный им же вопрос, даю ещё один ответ:

```sql
with t (ID, Attr) as (
    select 169, trim (column_value)
    from xmlTable ('"Jur9", "Jur9_name", "Jur10", "Jur10_name"') 
) 
select * from t
where regexp_like (attr, '^Jur\d+[^_]*$');
```

Результат:

```
        ID ATTR      
---------- ----------
       169 Jur9      
       169 Jur10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
  from table1
 where ID = 169
   and trim(translate(attr,'1234567890',' '))='JUR'
```

Answer (score 0):

_ означает любой одиночный символ.
можно вписать **ATTR like 'Jur_' or ATTR like 'Jur__'** или найти более лаконичное решение, исходя из документации по LIKE.

Comment: не правильно ведь, Jur__ вытащить только Jur10

Comment: а Jur_ вытащит Jur9. тут же не красного словца ради два условия через OR

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(ATTR, '^JUR[^_]+$')
```